# Write table with row name ordered after clustering in R's heatmap.2

Tags: r, heatmap

With the following code:

```
mydata <- mtcars
hclustfunc <- function(x) hclust(x, method="complete")
distfunc <- function(x) dist(x,method="euclidean")
heatmap.2(as.matrix(mydata),dendrogram="row",trace="none", margin=c(8,9), hclust=hclustfunc,distfun=distfunc);
```

I get the following heatmap:[image]

What I want to do is to save the result of the clustering in to a text file
but the row names are ordered as clustered result:

```
mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
Toyota Corolla 33.9 4 71.1 65 4.22 1.835 19.9 1 1 4 1
Porsche 914-2 26 4 120.3 91 4.43 2.14 16.7 0 1 5 2
Datsun 710 22.8 4 108 93 3.85 2.32 18.61 1 1 4 1
....
Maserati Bora 15 8 301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6 0 1 5 8
```

What's the way to do it ?
I tried this after `heatmap.2` line in the code above, but doesn't give
the result as I desired.

```
write.table(mydata, "~/Desktop/tmp.txt",row.names = TRUE, quote=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `heatmap.2` function won't do anything to your original data. If you save the results from the call to `heatmap.2` function, it will return the rowDendrogram that you can use to re-sort your data. For example

```
hh<-heatmap.2(as.matrix(mydata),dendrogram="row",
    trace="none", margin=c(8,9), 
    hclust=hclustfunc,distfun=distfunc);

sorted <- mydata[match(rev(labels(hh$rowDendrogram)), rownames(mydata)), ]

#view result
head(sorted)
#               mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# Datsun 710    22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Volvo 142E    21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
# Merc 230      22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Lotus Europa  30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

then you can write the sorted version of the data.frame to disk with `write.table`